# How to disavow on domain changed from http to https?

Tags: seo

Situation:
for about 2 years our business website ran on httpdomain; then a lot of websites hyperlinked to our website.

Now; we recently switched to https.domain ~ (redirection set on domain)
On some seo tools I can still see backlinks of good and bad sites linking to our http/domain.com ;

Primarily google-webmaster tools ~ we changed the domain on account to the httpsdomain already. verified thru analytics embed code put on the site.

the httpdomain is now set to be redirecting to our httpsdomain (same domain name just different in httpS).

Now; my question is
1. Will bad links linking to the httpdomain affect or pull down the httpSdomain site in rankings?

2. how can I disavow // or avoid association from the bad links for the httpsdomain?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google follow redirection very well, weather it is penalty or Juicyrank both pass through 301 redirection.

1. Yes the bad link to http version can heart https version of your website, because you have setup 301 redirection.
2. Create a list of all bad links (you might already have one for http version). That link list upload to https version of property.

Comment: Goyllo, Thanks, good point on #1. But... would it be that if I dosavow the bad links from the https webmastertool, but the badlink isnt really pointing to that https, then the disavow would be no effect?  should I be just instead blocking the traffic from the bad links?

Comment: Generally Google don't count those links because you have already provide that list on your http version, but for safety, you should also upload that list in https version also, since those links are bad. :)